# Not getting the simulate event to work to trigger click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a react component but somehow I am not able to get the simulate function to trigger the click and therefore I am not able to test the state variable or check for the function call of the click handler.

Here is the component code:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { Navbar,Nav,NavItem,NavDropdown,MenuItem,Panel } from 'react-
   bootstrap';
   import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

   class Header extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
     isLogOut : false
    };
    this.handleLogOut=this.handleLogOut.bind(this);

    }  
    handleLogOut(){
    this.setState({isLogOut:true});   
    }
    render() {
    return (
      <Navbar>
        <div className="network-nav-bar">
            <div className="network-nav-bar-items">
               <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#">Network Opimization</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quick links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">What If?</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-6">
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#" className="ancIndiLogo">INDi</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        </div>
        <div className="col-xs-6 noPadding">
       <Nav className="pull-right"> 
         <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Felicia Johnson" id="basic-nav-
    dropdown">
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.1} onClick=
   {this.handleLogOut}>LogOut</MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search pull-right"></i>
        </div>

 </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

and here is the spec file:-

```
'use strict';
  import React from 'react';
  import Header from '../modules/common/header';
  import {mount} from 'enzyme';
  describe('Testing the Header when', () => {
    it('the it should have text-center class', () => {
    const header = mount(
    <Header/>
   );
    expect(header.find('i .glyphicon-search').length).toBe(1);
   expect(header.find('a').length).toBe(6);
    console.log(header.state());
   console.log(header.find('a').get(5)).simulate('click');
      console.log(header.state());     
    expect(header.state().isLogOut).to.equal(true); 

});

});
```

Here is the package.json dependencies file :-
"enzyme": "^2.8.2".

Not sure what exactly is going wrong here..it should be a simple test.

Answer (score 1):

try using `.at(index)` instead of `.get(index)`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling simulate on the output of a console log.

Your code:
`console.log(header.find('a').get(5)).simulate('click');`

Should be:
`header.find('a').get(5).simulate('click');`

Comment: I have done that before...but only to see the output i have wrapped in console.log..problem is I am getting simulate is not a function.. and just wanted to confirm..do i need to import simulate just like i did for mount..from enzyme..as in the docs..nothing such is mentioned.

Comment: That's because you have only 4 `<a>` tags and you are doing `.get(5)`

Comment: I have fixed that..by giving an Id for that anchor tag..and then simulate click on it..and I have six anchor tags as i had a check to confirm this..i think it is the problem with enzyme..as the get function returns node..but that somehow does not work when you call simulate on it..

Comment: @Ayan I am facing the same issue, did you figure out how to work with simulate when the node is returned from get(index)